# trigger an element with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, triggers

following situation. I'm using a simple jQuery slider, depending on the tab you click on it changes the html content. I have the following classes:

`.tab1` `.tab2` etc.

What I would like to do is, to simulate a User-Mouse-Click on `.tab2`
Can you achieve this with jQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to simulate a event manually

```
$('.tab2').click() //or $('.tab2').trigger('click')
```

Form the comments
The problem is `.tab2` is the `li` element, but the click handler seems to be registered to the `a` element inside it so try

```
$('.tab2').find('a').click()
```

Comment: the trigger event is what I was looking for. But unfortunatly it does not trigger my slider, and I'm wondering what the trigger for the slider event is, if not the click.
edit: I attached an alert to see if its firing, and it does...

Comment: I can post a link to the side, one moment!

Comment: http://super-sized.de/delseit_php/ the trigger button for the "mouseclick" of the user is the red one at topleft. As you can see it triggers because it changes the button the the second tab. But the slider does not trigger! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

$('.tab2').trigger('click');

to simulate a User-Mouse-Click on .tab2

Comment: thats what I was looking for, but unfortunatly it does not trigger the slider. But it triggers the button, because I attached an alert.
But how would slider be triggered in that case, it should be a click on the button? umm

Answer (score 0):

Before that, make sure you bind the click event if you click on the element of the ajax response.

Please check  http://justprogrammer.com/2013/06/25/jquery-basic-concepts/ for ajax response.

After that, you could use

```
$('.tab2').click() //or $('.tab2').trigger('click')
```

I am binding using live method.

```
$('.tab2').live('click',function(){
  alert('here');
})
```